# remove duplicates on a 60 day rolling window in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script which removes duplicates on a 60 day rolling window. When a contact comes into the sheet, I need the sheet to look back 60 days from that point and not count it if it's a duplicate. The problem I am having with this script is that it continues to change prior day counts as time progresses through the month. It is changing the daily counts from prior days. Prior day counts should not be adjusted once the day is complete.
I just need a modification whereby after a day ends, it should not be changed in the future.
Here is the script;

```
const sheetName = 'Data';
const matchRecordsWithinDays = 60;

function removeDuplications() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const emails = sheet.getRange('F2:F').getValues().filter(String).map((x,index) => {
    return {
      email: x[0].toLowerCase().trim(),
      row: index + 2
    }
  });
  const dates = sheet.getRange('G2:G').getValues().map(x => x[0]).filter(String).map(x => new Date(x));

  let deletingRows = [];

  for(let i=0;i<emails.length;i++) {
    const data1 = emails[i];
    const matchingEmails = emails.filter(em => em.email === data1.email);

    for(let j=0;j<matchingEmails.length;j++) {
      const data2 = matchingEmails[j];

      if(data1.row > data2.row && isWithLastXDays(dates[data2.row-2]) && !deletingRows.includes(data2.row)) {
        deletingRows.push(data2.row);
      }
    }
  }

  let ui = null;
  try {
    ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  } catch(e) {}

  if(ui && deletingRows.length === 0) return ui.alert("No duplicates found!","There are no duplicate records found within last "+matchRecordsWithinDays+" days.", ui.ButtonSet.OK)

  deletingRows.sort((a,b) => {
    if(a > b) return -1;
    else if(a < b) return 1;
    else return 0
  })
  
  if(ui) {
    const response = ui.alert("Duplicated records found!","There are "+deletingRows.length+" duplicate records found within last "+matchRecordsWithinDays+" days, Press OK to delete them.", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    if(response == ui.Button.CANCEL) return;
  }

  deletingRows.forEach(row => {
    sheet.deleteRow(row);
  }); 
}

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Actions')
  .addItem('Remove duplications in last '+matchRecordsWithinDays+' days','removeDuplications')
  .addToUi();
}

function isWithLastXDays(date) {
  var deltaTime = Math.abs(date.getTime() - (new Date()).getTime());
  var deltaDays = deltaTime / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
  return deltaDays <= matchRecordsWithinDays;
}
```

Comment: Please share a sample sheet where the data is organized and try explaining with steps or more detail "prior days" what do you mean by that?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I7r2a8JwhUjKCUtB5_NfUC_blUSOfTSL1NRngwYdeOo/edit?usp=sharing Here is the sheet. You may take a look at it and maybe offer some help

Answer (score 0):

[image]

There is something wrong with dates out there in G column on you sheet. Did you do it deliberately? Different sorting order and different date formats are exactly the things that make this problem almost unsolvable. (Not to mention that I barely can understand what you trying to achieve.) It's surprisingly that the original script works somehow.

You need to decide how you will sort the dates (ascending or descending order) and select one format. I'd advice to stick with ISO format (2021-05-08 07:52:10).

It's not unlikely that the problem will disappear by itself after that.

Comment: the problem is in the 'daily tracking ' tab whereby the lead counts will continue to change once the day is over. Once a day is complete and there is a lead count shown on the daily tracking sheet then it should not change as more leads come in on future days. I have noticed that number of lead counts would get smaller every day for some reasons uknown to me.

Comment: I see your tables and still not able to understand what they do. Probably my knowledge in this area is not enough. There is some business logic that eludes me. Sorry. Perhaps I can get it if you tell me in plain words: number from a cell in column A add to a cell in column B if a cell in column C contains the the date between... etc.